# passing keyword argument to inner function when outer function has keyword argument with the same name

Tags: python, keyword-argument

I have two functions defined roughly like this:

```
def func_inner(bar=0):
    print('inner bar:', bar)
    
def func_outer(bar=-1, *args, **kwargs):
    print('outer bar:', bar)
    func_inner(*args, **kwargs)
```

Is there a way to call `func_outer` and provide it with two values of `bar` - one for `func_outer`, and the other to be passed over to `func_inner`? Calling `func_outer(bar=1,bar=2)` clearly does not work.

It's possible to overcome the issue by specifying `bar` values as positional arguments, like `func_outer(1,2)`, but I'd like to specify them as keyword arguments for both functions.

Is there a solution entirely at the caller's side (ie. without altering the functions)?

Answer (score 1):

### No, there is none

You cannot pass two arguments with the same name to a function. Thus, you will not be able to have the key `"bar"` in `kwargs`.

Thus you cannot pass this argument without modifying the two functions.

#### There may be a more adapted way to what you’re doing

This is the kind of code that pops up in a decorator. In this kind of case, you may want to make the outer function [currified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying).